# style sheet problems from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, stylesheet

Hi im trying to set the css style for this but I dont know whats happening I have this code from asp (code behind)

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
div.Style["float"] = "left";
Image img = new Image();
img.ImageUrl = "~/userdata/2/uploadedimage/batman-for-facebook.jpg";
img.AlternateText = "Test image";
div.Controls.Add(img);
test1.Controls.Add(div);

System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div1 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
div1.InnerText = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0));

div1.Style["float"] = "left";
test1.Controls.Add(div1);

System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div2 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
div2.Style["clear"] = "both";
test1.Controls.Add(div2);
```

which does this:

[image]

My css was originaly this:

```
div#test1 {
}
div#div
{
  width:90%; 
  z-index:1; 
  padding:27.5px; 
  border-top: thin solid #736F6E;
  border-bottom: thin solid #736F6E;
  color:#ffffff;
  margin:0 auto;
  white-space: pre;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  white-space: pre-line;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

But I dont know how to change the css now to reflect the changes in my code so that I can apply style to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always apply css to your div elements by

```
test1.Attributes["class"] = "yourCSS";
```

and include the css in your aspx file. You can also try

```
 test1.Attributes.Add("class", "yourCSS")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `test1.className = "nameofyourcss";`
or `test1.setAttribute("class", "nameofyourcss");`

Comment: test1 wont change the attributes of the divs inside test1 (test1 is just the container div)

Comment: Then use document.getElementsByTagName to get all the div elements within "test1" and apply the css to each div element using the aforementioned methods

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Literal instead of generating divs and images. I altered your code using Literal.

```
Literal literal1 = new Literal();
  literal1.Text =
  string.Format("<div style=\"float: left\"><img src='{0}' alt='Test Image'>
  </img></div>",ResolveUrl("~/userdata/2/uploadedimage/batman-for-facebook.jpg"));
  literal1 = new Literal();
  literal1.Text = string.Format("<div style=\"float: left\">{0}</div>", Reader.GetString(0));
  test1.Controls.Add(literal1);
  literal1 = new Literal();
  literal1.Text = "<div style=\"clear: both\">{0}</div>";
  test1.Controls.Add(literal1);
```

Comment: why with the div style? div style should be div id=test, test1 is just the containers for the div id=test 's It should be <div id=test1><div id=test>the image<img src></img> then the database text</END test div><END test1 div>

Comment: You programatically add float-> div.Style["float"] = "left"; To include css class and additional div.Style["float"] with using div alter literal.text to this  <div id="div" style="float: left">

Answer (score 0):

might want to try something like this by wrapping divs into one more. That is to give a top and bottom borders.

```
<style type="text/css">
        #test1 .desc
        {
            padding:27.5px; 
            float:left;
            height: 100px; 
        }
        #test1 .img
        {
            float:left;
            padding:27.5px;
        }
        #test1 > div.main
        {
        border-top: thin solid #736F6E;
        border-bottom: thin solid #736F6E;
        color:#000000;
        margin:0 auto;
        white-space: pre;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        white-space: pre-line;
        }
    </style>

System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl maindiv = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
            maindiv.Attributes["class"] = "main";

            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
            div.Attributes["class"] = "img";
            Image img = new Image();
            img.ImageUrl = "~/userdata/2/uploadedimage/batman-for-facebook.jpg";
            img.AlternateText = "Test image";
            div.Controls.Add(img);
            maindiv.Controls.Add(div);

            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div1 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
            div1.InnerText = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0));
            div1.Attributes["class"] = "desc";
            maindiv.Controls.Add(div1);

            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div2 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
            div2.Style["clear"] = "both";
            test1.Controls.Add(div2);
            test1.Controls.Add(maindiv);
```